# How can I tell if a liquid is (not) emitting light?

Tags: photochemistry, chemistry-in-fiction

I found an image of [Nuka Cola Quantim, a soft drink from the Fallout video game series,](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nuka-Cola_Quantum_%28Fallout_3%29) which depicts the bottle as glowing, but it doesn't feel quite real:

[image]

Then I also saw this video of a chemiluminescent reaction of luminol:

https://youtu.be/TJj7t2mrpxc

Experienced chemists and/or photo editors might tell right away which is real and which is fake. What hints should I look for when determining if a liquid itself is glowing or is being lit by a different light source?

Comment: unfortunately there is no "luminescence" tag and I don't know what else to pick

Comment: I doubt it's on-topic here, maybe on Skeptics SE would be.

Comment: I personally have no problem with having the question, but I agree, that it is not really on topic since the question is more about the picture than the chemistry which might be behind.

Comment: Tricky indeed, though it may be a useful question to discuss if fluorescence can be observed any easy way and distinguish from reflections.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be more related to photography and editing graphical images, and is probably better suited for an audience that specializes in producing/manipulating/enhancing images.

Comment: The bright line of light at the 'shoulder' of the bottle looks more like a reflection of a light source above. This looks more like the product of 3-D rendering software, of a pale blue liquid having a bright light cast on it from a line source.

Answer (score 6):

In a photograph, a light source is always brighter than any surface it is illuminating.

Therefore, if the liquid is the actual light source, the liquid should be significantly brighter than the rest of the bottle. See for example this picture by David Mülheims [CC BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5), via Wikimedia Commons:

[image: Luminol]

In the given picture, however, the parts above and below the water level have a similar brightness.

[image]